# Why does my shadcn ui DataTable not reload on invalidating query

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tanstackreact-query, shadcnui

I am using Nextjs, tanstack/react-query and shadcnui library. I have 3 components: Substance List, Shadcn DataTable and Shadcn Columns. Issue that I am facing is that upon deletion of the record the Table component doesnt rerender/reflect the deletion.

Substance List component

```
import { columns } from "./_components/columns";
import { DataTable } from "@/components/ui/data-table";

import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Substances() {
  const fetchSubstances = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/substances");
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  };

  const { data, isError, isLoading } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["substances"],
    queryFn: fetchSubstances,
  });

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto py-10">
      {!isLoading && (
        <DataTable
          columns={columns}
          data={data}
          createRoute="/substances/create"
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Columns component of Shadcnui -> where the delete / invalidate of query is triggered

```
"use client";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import axios from "axios";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";

import { useMutation, QueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";

import { ColumnDef } from "@tanstack/react-table";
import { MoreHorizontal } from "lucide-react";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownMenuContent,
  DropdownMenuItem,
  DropdownMenuLabel,
  DropdownMenuSeparator,
  DropdownMenuTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dropdown-menu";
import Link from "next/link";

import { Substance } from "@prisma/client";

export const columns: ColumnDef<Substance>[] = [
  {
    accessorKey: "name",
    header: "Name",
    cell: ({ row }) => {
      const substance = row.original;
      return (
        <Link
          href={`/substances/${substance.id}`}
          className="underline text-sky-700"
        >
          {substance.name}
        </Link>
      );
    },
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "type",
    header: "Type",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "EVcode",
    header: "EVcode",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "status",
    header: "Status",
  },
  {
    id: "actions",
    cell: ({ row }) => {
      const substance = row.original;
      const router = useRouter();
      const queryClient = new QueryClient();

      const handleEdit = (substanceId: string) => {
        console.log("click");
        console.log(substanceId);
        router.push(`/substances/${substanceId}`);
      };

      const { mutate: handleDeleteMutation } = useMutation({
        mutationFn: async (substanceId: string) => {
          await axios.delete("/api/substances", { data: { substanceId } });
        },
        onSuccess: () => {
          queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["substances"] });
          toast.success("Substance deleted");
        },
        onError: (err: any) => {
          toast.error("Substance not deleted");
        },
      });

      return (
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
            <Button variant="ghost" className="h-8 w-8 p-0">
              <span className="sr-only">Open menu</span>
              <MoreHorizontal className="h-4 w-4" />
            </Button>
          </DropdownMenuTrigger>
          <DropdownMenuContent align="end">
            <DropdownMenuLabel>Actions</DropdownMenuLabel>
            <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => handleEdit(substance.id)}>
              Edit
            </DropdownMenuItem>
            <DropdownMenuSeparator />
            <DropdownMenuItem>Copy</DropdownMenuItem>
            <DropdownMenuItem
              onClick={() => handleDeleteMutation(substance.id)}
            >
              Delete
            </DropdownMenuItem>
          </DropdownMenuContent>
        </DropdownMenu>
      );
    },
  },
];
```

In above code I am trying to achieve that the data table would refresh when item is deleted from it, however for some reason the shadcnui DataTable component doesnt rerender after the invalidation of the query. I would really appreaciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<DropdownMenuItem
              onClick={() => {handleDeleteMutation(substance.id); router.refresh()}}
            >
              Delete
            </DropdownMenuItem>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question will make it more useful for others in the future. Please consider updating your answer with some explanatory notes. Thanks